# Phrasal verbs and the position of object

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in the following sentences?

1. *They passed me over*.
2. *They passed over me*.

If yes, how, and please can anyone tell some similar examples?

Comment: Have you looked up 'pass over' (v) in General Reference (a basic requirement) ? Your question is getting closed for "lack of research".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to change the common structure in these phrasal verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/is-it-correct-to-change-the-common-structure-in-these-phrasal-verbs) Also [the placement of prepositions in phrasal verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111839/) and [Why can't you place pronouns after a phrasal verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250306/) and ["put X down to" vs. "put down X to": subjects of verbs with two particles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75792/), among others.

Comment: *They passed me over = They didn't select me* (phrasal verb use; ...for promotion at work, say). *They passed over me = They went by me overhead* (non-phrasal verb; "they" = planes, or birds, say).

Comment: In general, separable multi-word verbs are unseparated only when the object of the transitivising particle is a noun rather than a pronoun. They looked the answer up / They looked it up / They looked up the answer / *They looked up it.

Comment: _Over_ is a special case for Particle Shift. _She ran him over_ and _She ran over him_ are both grammatical, and can refer to the same event. Some people claim that the first one is deliberate while the second one is accidental. But I doubt everybody feels that way.

Comment: BTW...you have a bunch of grammarians here offering advice, but not  a formal answer. Those comments combined are great, and you should take them seriously. It is probably the only real answer you will get here.